# x86 Assembly: DIV operation with negative values

Tags: assembly, x86

I currently try to understand the `DIV` operation in context of following assembly code:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov eax [ebp+0x8]
mov edx, 0x0
div [ebp+0xC]
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

we have to calculate the return value. The function will be called with the following values:

1. func(3,24)
2. func(24,3)
3. func(24,-3)
4. func(-1,2)

The results for 1) and 2) are 0 and 8 in my opinion.

Now I want to calculate the results for 3) and 4). As I know that the `DIV` operation works with unsigned integers my first question is, how to present -3 and -1?

I would proceed as follows:

1. build the two's compliment of param2
2. perform a binary division

Regarding the third situation:

> -3 is in two's compliment: 11111101

so

> div: (24) 0001100 / 11111101

What would be the result?

And the fourth one:

> -1: 11111111

so

> div: (-1) 11111111 / 10
>   divison with 2 = shr 1 -> 1111111 -> 127

Could you please help me to verify the results?

Comment: I guess people following the HTML tag will be quite surprised by this question...

Comment: @rcgldr: `DIV` is the unsigned form of the instruction, so rounding towards zero and negative infinity somewhat hard to distinguish. I rather think this question calls for `IDIV`

Answer (score 2):

`eax` is a 32-bit register.
This means that the div will work on 32-bit operands, not byte values like you seem to think.
-3 in 2's complement is `FFFFFFFD` in hex = `‭4294967293‬` in decimal.
-1 in 2's complement is `FFFFFFFF` in hex = `4294967295` in decimal.

You can easily perform the calculations using any calculator. 
If you want to divide with byte values, you should use

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
xor eax,eax                 ;mov eax,0
mov al, [ebp+0x8]
div al, byte ptr [ebp+0xC]
xor edx,edx
mov dl,ah                   ;put the remainder in edx
xor ah,ah
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

The section

```
xor edx,edx
mov dl,ah                   ;remainder in edx
xor ah,ah
```

Can be simplified to

```
movzx edx,ah                ;mov byte value with zero extend to full reg
xor ah,ah
```

The result will be stored in `al` and the remainder in `ah`.
Because Intel uses little endian, it does not matter that you're only using a single byte, the `mov al,[some_address_as_before]` will still work.
*On a big endian architecture you'd need to adjust the address by 3 bytes.*

If you're clearing a register it's usually better to use `xor a,a` than using `mov reg,0` the former encodes in fewer bytes and runs faster.

**Further reading**
http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html

Comment: thanks, your right, I havn't realizied that the eax is a 32-bit register :) now it make sense